How to stick a curve in a mesh that can put array on to follow the arrayed object to the mesh?
Hello everybody so I wanted to make objects to follow a certain path and be directly on the line I tried using Array Curve for the object and Shrinkwrap so the Curve line will stick to the Surface Mesh but the Array Curve isn't working and putting curve line takes too much long of a time. Is there a faster way to put Curve Lines or maybe just draw over it to use the array or is that the only way? Also is what I'm doing wrong when using array? 


